# add telerik asp.net ajax controls to asp.net mvc views

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, telerik

I am looking for any tutorial or document about how to use telerik asp.net ajax controls with asp.net mvc views

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need the [Telerik ASP.NET MVC extensions](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/).  They have usage examples on their website.

Comment: cant find the info I need on their site

Answer (score 0):

Telerik makes purpose-built tools for ASP.NET MVC, as Robert noted. The Telerik Extensions for ASP.NET MVC have been built from the ground-up to embrace the MVC platform, meaning:

- They're based on jQuery
- They work with any MVC ViewEngine (including the new Razor)
- They easily integrate with Controllers / Actions
- They're open source!

You can [visit the online demos](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc), or you can read more on Telerik.com:

http://www.telerik.com/mvc

This is by far the best way to build rich MVC Views, but if you are set on using the RadControls for ASP.NET AJAX in MVC, that can be done. The approach has drawbacks since the RadControls are built for WebForms, but you can find an example implementation here:

http://demos.telerik.com/mvc/Home/Help

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

[Telerik has a help topic on precisely this question](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/mvc-radcontrols-for-aspnet-mvc-overview.html).

Using the ASP.NET AJAX controls can be done but as others have said, Telerik has also provides native MVC extensions, called [Kendo UI](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-mvc.aspx).